# Which files in the Avast virus chest have been restored?

Tags: windows-7, avast

Is there any way to see which files in the Avast virus chest have been restored? When I restore a file, it doesn't disappear from the virus chest list.

I would like to be able to see which files have been restored without having to check whether they are present in their original location, and I don't want to have to try to restore them either (Avast will ask me whether I want to overwrite in case the file have been restored).

[image]